# Refresh the Fragment when items of ListView are Deleted

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My app is a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` and Tabs to the top.
I have 4 sections that 2 of them share 2 values int and float stored in SharedPreferences.

In one of this Fragments is take back data from DB and show in a `ListView`!
When i add data i haven't problem, the sharedpreferences change and the `TextView` is setted with the new value.

The problem appear when i delete item from the `ListView`.
This `ListView` have a button inside "X" for delete row, when i delete it i recalculate the new average and store it in the SharedPreferences, but the values in the `TextView` don't change with the new result!

Here the Adapter

```
public class VotiEsamiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VotiEsami> {

    public MySQLiteHelper db;
    private List<VotiEsami> searchArrayList;
    private List<VotiEsami> esami_tot;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;


    public VotiEsamiAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List objects ){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        searchArrayList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_voti_line, null);

        db = new MySQLiteHelper(getContext());

        final TextView nome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_line_voto_nome);
        final TextView cfu = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_line_voto_cfu);
        TextView voto = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_line_voto_valore);

        VotiEsami m = getItem(position);

        // inflate other items here :
        ImageButton delete_row_button = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_line_voti);

        delete_row_button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        searchArrayList.remove(position);
                        db.deleteSelectedVotoEsame(nome.getText().toString());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //Carico la media pesata e i cfu totale con sharedpreferences
                        sharedPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("USR_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        //Aggiorno media e CFU
                        //Get all exams inside database
                        esami_tot = db.getVotiEsami();
                        float MEDIA_PONDERATA;
                        float media_parziale;
                        float media_sommata_parziale = 0;
                        int CFU_SOMM = 0;

                        if (esami_tot.isEmpty()) {

                            CFU_SOMM = 0;
                            MEDIA_PONDERATA = 0;
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "EMPTY!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {

                            //Calcolare media totale e CFU totale
                            for (VotiEsami exams : esami_tot) {

                                int voto_temp = exams.get_voto();

                                if (voto_temp == 31) voto_temp = 30;
                                media_parziale = (voto_temp) * (exams.get_cfu());
                                CFU_SOMM += exams.get_cfu();
                                media_sommata_parziale += media_parziale;

                            }
                            MEDIA_PONDERATA = media_sommata_parziale / CFU_SOMM;

                        }
                        //Salvo i dati
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putFloat("MEDIA", MEDIA_PONDERATA);
                        editor.putInt("CFU", CFU_SOMM);

                    }

                }

        );

        nome.setText(m.get_nome_esame());
        cfu.setText("CFU: " + String.valueOf(m.get_cfu()));
        if(m.get_voto() == 31) {

            voto.setText("Voto: " + String.valueOf(m.get_voto()-1) + "L");

        }else{

            voto.setText("Voto: " + String.valueOf(m.get_voto()));

        }

        //Se la media è inferiore al 6 lo scrivo in rosso
        //altrimenti in verde
        if(m.get_voto() <= 21) {

            voto.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.rosso));

        }else if ((m.get_voto() <= 25) && (m.get_voto() >= 22)){

            voto.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.giallo));

        }else if((m.get_voto() >= 25) && (m.get_voto() <=31)){

            voto.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));

        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here the Fragment that manage and show this data

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    public MySQLiteHelper db;
    public List<VotiEsami> esami;
    public VotiEsamiAdapter adapter; //Adapter per caricare la listview di voti

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        //Carico la media pesata e i cfu totale con sharedpreferences
        sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("USR_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int defaultValueInt = 0;

        float SharedMedia = sharedPref.getFloat("MEDIA", defaultValueInt);
        int SharedCFU = sharedPref.getInt("CFU", defaultValueInt);

        TextView media_top = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_media);
        TextView cfu_top = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_tot_cfu);

        media_top.setText("Media: " + String.valueOf(SharedMedia));
        cfu_top.setText("CFU TOT: " + String.valueOf(SharedCFU));

        //Find the listview
        final ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.voti_listView);

        //Get all exams inside database
        esami = db.getVotiEsami();
        adapter = new VotiEsamiAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_voti_line, esami);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        float MEDIA_PONDERATA;
        float media_parziale;
        float media_sommata_parziale = 0;
        int CFU_SOMM = 0;

        if(!esami.isEmpty()) {
            //Calcolare media totale e CFU totale
            for (VotiEsami exams : esami) {

                int voto_temp = exams.get_voto();

                if (voto_temp == 31) voto_temp = 30;
                media_parziale = (voto_temp) * (exams.get_cfu());
                CFU_SOMM += exams.get_cfu();
                media_sommata_parziale += media_parziale;

            }
            MEDIA_PONDERATA = media_sommata_parziale / CFU_SOMM;
        }else{

            MEDIA_PONDERATA = 0;

        }
        //Salvo i dati
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putFloat("MEDIA", MEDIA_PONDERATA);
        editor.putInt("CFU", CFU_SOMM);

        //TODO gestire cancellazione del voto dal DB e dalla listview


        Button nuovo_voto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add_new_voto);
        nuovo_voto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Start Dialog for input the new vote
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DialogAddVotoEsame.class);
                ThreeFragment.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);

            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        List<VotiEsami> esami_per_media;

        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String result_nome = data.getStringExtra("result_name_esame"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int result_cfu = data.getIntExtra("result_cfu_esame", 1); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int result_voto = data.getIntExtra("result_voto_esame", 1); //Take the materia from Dialog

                //Add exam with vote to DB
                db.addEsameVoto(new VotiEsami(result_nome, result_cfu, result_voto));

                esami_per_media = db.getVotiEsami();

                float MEDIA_PONDERATA;
                float media_parziale;
                float media_sommata_parziale = 0;
                int CFU_SOMM = 0;

                //TODO calcolare media totale e CFU totale
                for (VotiEsami exams : esami_per_media) {

                    int voto_temp = exams.get_voto();
                    if(voto_temp == 31) voto_temp = 30;
                    media_parziale = (voto_temp) * (exams.get_cfu());
                    CFU_SOMM += exams.get_cfu();
                    media_sommata_parziale += media_parziale;

                }
                MEDIA_PONDERATA = media_sommata_parziale/CFU_SOMM;

                //Salvo i dati
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putFloat("MEDIA", MEDIA_PONDERATA);
                editor.putInt("CFU", CFU_SOMM);
                editor.commit();

                TextView media_top = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_media);
                TextView cfu_top = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_tot_cfu);

                media_top.setText("Media: " + String.valueOf(MEDIA_PONDERATA));
                cfu_top.setText("CFU TOT: " + String.valueOf(CFU_SOMM));

                //Refresh list
                List<VotiEsami> newesame = db.getVotiEsami();

                //Aggiorno la Listview dell'activity con il nuovo inserimento
                esami.clear();
                esami.addAll(newesame);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }
    }//onActivityResult

}
```

How can i change the values of `TextView` if i delete one ore two rows in the `ListView`?
The main problem appear when i delete because i can't `findViewById` the `TextView` of the `Fragments` in the `Adapter`.
Is there some way to do that? Can i find a `TextView` inside the `Fragment` from the `Adapter`?

Comment: try adapter.notify();

Comment: Where, in the Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is using an interface.

First you have to create the interface and "launch" the event:

```
public class VotiEsamiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VotiEsami> {

    private OnDeleteButtonClicked onDeleteButtonClicked;
    ...

    public VotiEsamiAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List objects, OnDeleteButtonClicked onDeleteButtonClicked){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        searchArrayList = objects;
        this.onDeleteButtonClicked = onDeleteButtonClicked;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ...
        delete_row_button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        ...
                        //Salvo i dati
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putFloat("MEDIA", MEDIA_PONDERATA);
                        editor.putInt("CFU", CFU_SOMM);

                        onDeleteButtonClicked.onDeleteClick();
                    }
                }
        );
        ...
    }
    ...
    public interface OnDeleteButtonClicked {
        void onDeleteClick();
    }
```

And then you have to implement the method in your fragment:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements VotiEsamiAdapter.OnDeleteButtonClicked{
...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        adapter = new VotiEsamiAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_voti_line, esami, this);
        ...
    }
    ... 
    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick() {
        media_top.setText("Media: " + String.valueOf(SharedMedia));
        cfu_top.setText("CFU TOT: " + String.valueOf(SharedCFU));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So with this, the method delete is owned by the Fragment and not by the Adapter, right?

Comment: Technically method onDeleteClick is owned by its interface and Fragment is "obligated" to implement this method.

Comment: I will try this! Thanks! If it's works i will check!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass reference to ThreeFragment into VotiAdapter (in constructor) and then use it to find view and replace text.
For more clean solution instead of passing reference to fragment you can define new callback listener and implement it by ThreeFragment. VotiAdapter could call method of this interface when it needs to inform fragment of status change.